# JavaMail in an enterprise application: why using JNDI?

Tags: jakarta-mail, jndi

To access a database from an enterprise application we always use a DataSource (instead of performing a direct access through DriverManager) because behind it there is a connection pool that improves performance, but what about JavaMail sessions?  What are the benefits of using JNDI to lookup a JavaMail session instead of creating one by calling `javax.mail.Session.getInstance(Properties props)`?  Is it useful only to configure the mail server address in a standard way?

Answer (score 0):

The reason to lookup the JavaMail Session in JNDI is that it allows the app server administrator to configure the Session without modifying the application.